# Domain of a function with fractional part expression

Tags: functions

It goes like : find domain of $f(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{(\{x+1\}-x^{2}+2x)}}$ where {.} denotes fractional part of x.
I went on with the usual methodology putting denominator greater than 0,

$\{x+1\}-(x)^{2}+2x>0$

I changed fractional part to (x+1)-[x+1] where [.] denoted greatest integer function.

solving further,
$3x-(x)^{2}+1>[x+1]$
$3x-(x)^{2}>[x]$
after this i tried making graph of this but to no avail as i couldn't specify the exact points satisfying the condition. Algebraically I'm not able to make out the next step. Any clues will be helpful,thanks in advance!

Comment: This can help, perhaps: For one thing you need to have $(x^2 - 2x<1)$ to make sure that the denominator is not negative (otherwise it is negative and the square root is not defined). Then you can break into cases, try considering one case: $x^2-2x<-1$  and then separately another case: $-1<x^2-2x<1$

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

Recall that $x-1<[x]$ for all real $x.$